Greasemonkey: Listening on if table gets "refreshed"
I am working on a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script that adds a new column to a table on this page https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league.
I have a working version that adds the column and it looks like so

I want to be able to re-run the script when the grid gets refreshed (for instance when one of the table headers gets clicked to sort the data). The problem is that if I add code to observe the table for when it changes, it fires when I add the column. I do notice that when changes to the page happen, a div is added to the DOM that has a class called "fgui-loading". Is there a way to add an observer for that div AFTER the initial page load?
Here is my working script that adds the column but as you can see sorting the columns does not update the last one.

(function () {
  "use strict";

  // Mock function to get the free agent year of a player
  function getFreeAgentYear(playerName) {
    // In a real scenario, this data would be fetched from an API or database
    let freeAgentData =
      {
"Aaron Judge" : "FREE AGENT 2029",
"Juan Soto" : "After 2030"
};
    return freeAgentData[playerName] || "Not on Roster or After 2030";
  }

  // Function to add the "Free Agent Year" column
  function addFreeAgentYearColumn() {
    const table = document.querySelector(".table-scroll");
    if (!table) return;

    // Add the header for the new column
    const headerRow = table.querySelector("thead tr");
    if (headerRow) {
      const newHeader = document.createElement("th");
      newHeader.innerText = "Club Control";
      headerRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    }

    // Add the free agent year data for each player
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    rows.forEach((row) => {
      const playerNameCell = row.querySelector("td a");
      if (playerNameCell) {
        const playerName = playerNameCell.innerText.trim();
        const freeAgentYear = getFreeAgentYear(playerName);

        const newCell = document.createElement("td");
        newCell.innerText = freeAgentYear;
        row.appendChild(newCell);
      }
    });
  }

  const initialObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    var processed = false;
    mutations.forEach(() => {
      if (document.querySelector(".table-scroll")) {
        if (document.querySelector(".table-scroll")) {
          const table = document.querySelector(".table-scroll");
          if (
            table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").length > 1 &&
            processed == false
          ) {
            addFreeAgentYearColumn();
            processed = true;
            initialObserver.disconnect();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

  initialObserver.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
})();


Appreciate the help on this!

Observing the .fgui-loading will not solve the problem, as that element only appears when fetching data from the network, once the data has been cached it won't appear anymore.
Neither will listening for clicks on the header, as you still need to make sure the load/refresh is finished and the new values are inserted, so that your function does not use the previous values.
The easiest/simplest approach is to observe the tbody element and call addFreeAgentYearColumn whenever it is updated.
This conveniently handles changing the page number or page size, and even changing tabs.
Note: I only tested this code on the major league page and it's tabs, you might need to adjust it to work on other pages.
function getFreeAgentYear(playerName) {
    let freeAgentData =
        {
            "Aaron Judge" : "FREE AGENT 2029",
            "Juan Soto" : "After 2030"
        };
    return freeAgentData[playerName] || "Not on Roster or After 2030";
}


function addFreeAgentYearColumn() {
    const table = document.querySelector("div.table-scroll > table");
    if (!table) return;

    // disconnect observer to avoid infinite loop
    observer.disconnect();

    // remove old header/cells (from tables that don't have player names and avoid duplication)
    table.querySelectorAll('#club-control').forEach( ele => ele.remove() );

    // return if this table does not have a playerName header
    const playerNameHeader = table.tHead.querySelector("th[data-col-id=Name]");
    if (!playerNameHeader) return;

    const clubControlHeader = document.createElement("th");
    clubControlHeader.innerText = "Club Control";
    clubControlHeader.id = "club-control";
    table.tHead.rows[0].appendChild(clubControlHeader);

    const rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
    for (let i=0; i < rows.length; ++i){
        //const playerNameCell = rows[i].cells[1];
        const playerNameCell = rows[i].querySelector("td[data-col-id=Name]");
        if (!playerNameCell) return;

        const playerName = playerNameCell.textContent;
        const freeAgentYear = getFreeAgentYear(playerName);

        const clubControlCell = document.createElement("td");
        clubControlCell.id = "club-control";
        clubControlCell.innerText = freeAgentYear;
        rows[i].appendChild(clubControlCell);
    };

    // reconnect the observer
    const target = table.tBodies[0];
    const config = {childList: true, subtree: true};
    observer.observe(target, config);
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(addFreeAgentYearColumn);
addFreeAgentYearColumn();

